# Apache doesnt have access to Cert file

Tags: python, apache, ssl

I am trying to send an Apple push notification. I can send it from the Python shell:

```
import apns
ns=apns.APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file="certs/C.pem", key_file="certs/C.pem")
ns.gateway_server.send_notification('TOKEN', apns.Payload(alert='hi'))
```

However, when I try and send it from the webserver, I get the same error I would get if I was in a folder that doesn't have access to my `certs` directory:

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 336265218] _ssl.c:356: error:140B0002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:system lib
```

I have the main project folder in my apache.conf file:

```
<Directory /home/ubuntu/MyProject/Django/MyProject>
   <Files *>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

The cert folder is located at `/home/ubuntu/MyProject/Django/MyProject/certs`. How would I give apache access to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an absolute path to the certification file. Python will most likely load the project `HOME` but for apache it needs the full path.